# NSDictionary check for null

Tags: objective-c, nsnull

Is there a quick method for determining if a value is NSNULL in a dictionary without checking for that objects class like

`[[dict objectForKey:@"foo"] class] != [NSNull null];`

Comment: Not sure why the downvote, the other questions & answers aren't very satisfying.

Comment: This might help http://stackoverflow.com/a/21982611/210171 (An answer I gave about dealing w null values)

Comment: (i.e. you can do something like `id found = [dict[@"foo"] ifNullThenNil]`)

Comment: The above test does not check for null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually what you have posted is not correct , you are comparing class ( NSNull ) to the singleton instance of this class ( NSNull null ) ,

the correct would be

```
[[dict objectForKey:@"foo"] isKindOfClass:[NSNull class]];
```

or comparing the instances

```
[dict objectForKey:@"foo"] == [NSNull null];
```

but if you have lots of this calls , you can create a category of NSDictionary and add method there , something like

```
- (BOOL)nl_isNSNullAt:(id)key {
    return [[self objectForKey:key] isKindOfClass:[NSNull class]];
}
```

or with instances

```
- (BOOL)nl_isNSNullAt:(id)key {
    return [self objectForKey:key] == [NSNull null];
}
```

then you can directly access

```
[dict nl_isNSNullAt:@"foo"]
```

You can of course choose the name of the method and category ...

Comment: Yeah, ok, I'll do this.. just wish there was a way around it. Thank you

Comment: To be consistent with Cocoa coding guidelines a better name for that method would be `isNullForKey:`. However, note that methods you add in categories on framework classes should always be prefixed with your project prefix, e.g. `xyz_isNullForKey:`.

Answer (score 6):

While you can do what ogres says, you should preferably use:

```
id someObject = [dict objectForKey:@"foo"];
if (someObject != [NSNull null]){
   //do something
}
```

As [NSNull null] is a singleton and only one of them ever exists, you can perform a direct comparison. This is what is used in the documentation here:

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/NumbersandValues/Articles/Null.html

> To test for a null object value, you must therefore make a direct object comparison.

This is the preferred method.

EDIT: This was written before Ogres edited their post to use an identity comparison.

Answer (score 3):

Compare the value, not the class.

```
dict[@"foo"] == [NSNull null]
```

The `null` method returns a singleton instance of `NSNull`. Since only one instance of `NSNull` is ever allocated, you can directly compare the instance's address to the addresses of collection elements to determine whether any of them are conceptually null.

Comment: Why, because it's less operations? Same result either way AFAICS

Comment: @quantumpotato `NSNull`'s `null` class method returns a singleton reference, which allows you to do identity comparison here.